# antipodal map from sphere to projective space is immersion and submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

Define a map $\mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ given by $x \mapsto \{ x,-x\}.$
Clearly this is not a diffeomorphism, but how can one show that it is an immersion and submersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a local diffeomorphism, and the result follows.

Comment: yes, by definition I think immersion & submersion means local diffeomorphism, but how do you prove it is local diffeom?

Comment: @Nicolo' Note that $S^n_+=\{x\in S^n, x_0>0\}$ can be the local charts of both $S^n$ and $RP^n$, what is the antipodal map in this chart?

Comment: it is the identity, so we get a local diffeomorphism, right?

Comment: @Nicolo' You got it.